# Python's tkinter Buttons - How to get return values of functions from other buttons?

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

I am working on a tkinter interface for an assignment that opens a file, reads and modifies it, then outputs it to a new file. I have buttons that, when clicked, let the user browse their computer for the appropriate files. Those separate functions return the filename ("randomInputFile.txt").

My problem is that I have a third button that should take those two values and then use them in the reading/writing process. I'm not sure how to pass the input/output filenames as parameters to the read/write function.

**Should I just pass the filenames as global variables within the respective function?**

```
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename
def openGUI():
    wn = Tk()
    wn.title("Homework 10 - CSIS 153")

    openFileButton = Button(wn, text="Open", command = openFile)
    openFileButton.pack()
    openFileButton.place(bordermode=OUTSIDE, height=90, width=90)

    saveFileButton = Button(wn, text="Save to...", command =  saveFile)
    saveFileButton.pack()
    saveFileButton.place(bordermode=OUTSIDE, height=90, width=90, x=110, )

    executeButton = Button(wn, text="Run Program", command = splitSentences(****SOMETHING, SOMETHING****))
    executeButton.pack()
    executeButton.place(bordermode=OUTSIDE, height=90, width=123, x=40, y=115)

    wn.mainloop()

def openFile():
    inputFile = askopenfilename()
    msg = "You are opening:\n\n" + str(inputFile)
    messagebox.showinfo("File Location", msg)
    return inputFile

def saveFile():
    outputFile = asksaveasfilename()
    return outputFile
def splitSentences(inFile, outFile):
    with open(inFile) as myFile:
        #etc etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `return` anything to a Button, so there's no use in those lines at the end of the functions. And yes, the easiest thing to do would be to make `inputFile` and `outputFile` global variables. Then, you also wouldn't need to pass them as an argument to `splitSentences()`, that function would just access them directly.

However, the better way to do it would be to make your GUI a class, and those variables as instance variables. You should also provide some way to disable the `executeButton` until you have values for the `inputFile` and `outputFile` variables, otherwise that function will throw an error.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. As this is for a school assignment, I'll just write in some preconditions or raise some related error messages.